# how to return from promise.all in typescript?

Tags: typescript, promise, promise.all

I have a list of urls which I need to fetch all of them so I used fetch and then promise.all, However, I don't know how to return the result of promises.

```
let photos_info = [];
function get_photos(urls) {
  var promises = urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((y) => y.json()));
  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  
  console.log("results:", results);
  photos_info = [...results];
  console.log("photos_info:", photos_info );
  });

  return photos_info ;
}

const list_of_photos = get_photos(urls);
console.log("result of the function", list_of_photos);
```

why list_of_photos returns an empty list however when printing the photos_info inside the function, it return the list.

Comment: You cannot convert a promise to a synchronous result, you will have to await it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

**It's because your Promise.all run asynchronously**

So `return photos_info` will run before it got the response to result in an undefined.

Change it to:

```
let photos_info = [];
async function get_photos(urls) {
  var promises = urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((y) => y.json()));
  await Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  
  console.log("results:", results);
  photos_info = [...results];
  console.log("photos_info:", photos_info );
  });

  return photos_info ;
}

const list_of_photos = get_photos(urls);
console.log("result of the function", list_of_photos);
```

**The reason you get a response inside  your console log is that it inside a `then` block, that block only run after a promise response successful (which is also asynchronously)**

Comment: `list_of_photos` will be a promise since `get_photos` is an `async` function.

Comment: Thank you! but I have 2 questions, I read a lot about promises but still don't get how  return photos_info will run before it got the response to result, and the second question the list_of_photos is still a promise so how can I return the list?